# ReferenceError: window is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.post("/web/suggest_oncall", function(req, res){
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
           var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
           var vars = query.split("&");
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
           }
           return(false);
    }
    console.log(getQueryVariable("list"));
});
```

I am trying to pull the value of "list" from the query and display it in the console. What exactly can I do for window to be recognized?

Comment: @adeneo what do I do for it to recognize then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously, there is no `window` on a server, but `req.url` should contain the current URL.

```
app.post("/web/suggest_oncall", function(req, res){
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
           var url   = req.url; // gets the URL
           var query = url.split('?').pop().substring(1);
           var vars = query.split("&");
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
           }
           return(false);
    }
    console.log(getQueryVariable("list"));
});
```